# Pseudo XML to CSV

Tags: xml, bash

I have got a file with the following content:

```
<AA>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT1</BB>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT2</BB>
</AA>
<AA>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT3</BB>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT4</BB>
</AA>
<AA>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT5</BB>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT6</BB>
</AA>
```

What is the best way to transform it to CSV like:

```
RANDOM TEXT1,RANDOM TEXT2
RANDOM TEXT3,RANDOM TEXT4
RANDOM TEXT5,RANDOM TEXT6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to parse XML is with an XML parser.

First step, to "fix" the pseudo-XML into proper XML:

```
$ { echo '<root>'; cat file; echo '</root>'; }
<root>
<AA>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT1</BB>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT2</BB>
</AA>
<AA>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT3</BB>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT4</BB>
</AA>
<AA>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT5</BB>
  <BB>RANDOM TEXT6</BB>
</AA>
</root>
```

Then, extract the BB values with an XML parser, here using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

```
$ { echo '<root>'; cat file; echo '</root>'; } | xmlstarlet sel -t -v //BB
RANDOM TEXT1
RANDOM TEXT2
RANDOM TEXT3
RANDOM TEXT4
RANDOM TEXT5
RANDOM TEXT6
```

Then, join pairs of lines

```
... | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//BB' | paste -d, - -
RANDOM TEXT1,RANDOM TEXT2
RANDOM TEXT3,RANDOM TEXT4
RANDOM TEXT5,RANDOM TEXT6
```

---

It can be done with xmlstarlet's options without using paste, at the expense of readability:

```
... | xmlstarlet sel -t -m //AA -v 'BB[1]' -o ',' -v 'BB[2]' -n
RANDOM TEXT1,RANDOM TEXT2
RANDOM TEXT3,RANDOM TEXT4
RANDOM TEXT5,RANDOM TEXT6
```